# Constant space short circuiting `foldM` over `Maybe`

Tags: haskell

Lets say I have the following:

```
f :: b -> a -> b
x :: b
l :: [a]
```

and

```
foldl' f x l
```

runs in constant space. That is `f` is suitably strict.

Now consider if I have:

```
f2 :: b -> a -> Maybe b
f2 x y = if (pred x y) then Just $! (f x y) else Nothing
```

will

```
foldM f2 x l
```

reliably run in constant space? Or is there something else I need to do to ensure I have both constant space but still the short circuiting behaviour of `Maybe`?

(Note whilst I've asked this question about `Maybe`, I actually want to do this with `Either`, but I suspect the approach is similar)

Comment: Mh! Maybe you need to use the tail recursion to acive the constant space with f2?

Comment: looks to me FWIW like it indeed should run in constant space, provided as you said that f is suitably strict.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the library source code `foldM` is defined as `foldlM`, which in turn is defined as

```
foldlM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b
foldlM f z0 xs = foldr c return xs z0
  where c x k z = f z x >>= k
```

Assuming, `c x k z = f2 z x >>= k`, let's see what happens when we call it. To see if it's constant space or not, we will only reduce the expressions by applying the topmost function without reducing the subexpressions.

```
foldlM f2 z0 (x:xs)
=
foldr c return (x:xs) z0
=
c x (foldr c return xs) z0
=
f2 z0 x >>= foldr c return xs
```

Since `>>=` is strict on the first arg, we evaluate `f2 z0 x` first. If that returns `Nothing`, we ignore the rest (short-circuiting, as you mentioned). If that returns `Just y`, we have

```
Just y >>= foldr c return xs
=
foldr c return xs y
```

and we are ready for the next loop.

This did not cause our term to grow, so it looks like it runs in constant space (provided `f2` keeps the size of `y` constant, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So do we even need the `$!` strictness annotation or can it be dropped?

Comment: I think I do need the `$!` annotation to on `Right $!` to ensure we're forcing `y` at every step, but your answer doesn't clarify this (and I'm not sure whether I'm right or wrong here) so I would appreciate it if you address this. Many thanks again for going through this so meticulously.

Comment: @Clinton You do need that annotation... or maybe not, depending on `pred`. Even if `y` is unevaluated when we create `Just y`, at the next step we pass that `y` to `f2` which calls `pred`, which is likely to force it. If `pred` is strict on that argument, `y` is not kept unevaluated. Or, more generally, we need that `f2` is strict on that argument. You might want to write `f2 x !y = ...` if `pred` is not strict enough. Or keep writing `Just $! f x y`.